# How to use the string bool expression to filter a list

Tags: python, string, boolean-expression

I have a bool expression `age_str = "age<=3"`
and a age list `age_list = [1,2,3,4]`,how to use the age_stri to filter the age_list?
the expected output is `[1,2,3]`

Comment: Since there are already two answers with `eval` you should be aware of possible problems: [Eval really is dangerous](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)

Comment: so is there any other better way? In fact，I have more than one bool expression, such as 'age<=3', 'day>10','salary>1000' , i want to use these string to filter some data

Answer (score 1):

You can use eval for this:

```
age_str = "age<=3"
age_list = [1,2,3,4]
res = []

for age in age_list:
    if eval(age_str):
        res.append(age)

print(res)
```

result:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

A list comprehension with eval will do the trick:

```py
age_str = "age<=3"
age_list = [1,2,3,4]
ages = [age for age in age_list if eval(age_str)]
print(ages)
```